# Understanding equation for capacitor-voltage

Tags: capacitor

For an simple RC-network the following solution of an ODE is given:

\$u_c=A_1+A_2\cdot e^{\frac{t}{\tau}}\$

I fully understand how the solution is calculated, but I want to have an feeling for it..

Am I right if I say that \$A_1\$ is the Voltage that would be across the C if the actual circuit would remain like it is for \$t -> \inf\$?

and \$A_2\$ is the voltage defined like:

\$A_2\$ = actual voltage over the C - \$A_1\$

Is my assumption right?

Comment: You have an unstable system. You should change the exponent to -t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it more intuitive to interpret the solution as

$$v(t) = A_1 - A_2 \times e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}$$

Now \$A_1\$ is the **final** voltage, at \$t = \infty\$. The value of \$A_2\$ is how much the voltage will **change**, from \$t=0\$ to \$t=\infty\$. In other words, \$A_1 -A_2\$ is the **initial** value of the voltage.

When \$t = 0\$, \$e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} = 1\$ so \$v(0) = A_1 - A_2\$ as expected.

As \$t \to \infty\$, \$e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} \to 0\$ so \$v(\infty) \to A_1\$ as expected.

Comment: yes, thats intuitive! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> \$A_1\$ is the voltage that will be across the C if the actual circuit would remain like it is for \$t \rightarrow \infty\$

It looks the exponential components lacks a sign. \$e^{+xt}\$ goes to \$\infty\$ when \$t \rightarrow \infty\$.
But with a minus sign, yes, your understanding is correct. $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} u_c = \lim_{x \to \infty} (A_1+A_2\cdot e^{\color{red}{-}\frac{t}{\tau}}) = A_1 $$

\$A_1\$ is the steady state value.

---

> \$A_2\$ = actual voltage over the C - \$A_1\$

\$u_c\$ is the actual voltage over the C. So, substituting this in your statement:
$$A_2 = u_c - A_1 $$
But, \$u_c\$ has been defined as
$$ u_c = A_1+A_2\cdot e^{\color{red}{-}\frac{t}{\tau}} $$
Substiting \$u_c\$ yields

$$u_c - A_1 = (A_1+A_2\cdot e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}})-A_1 = A_2\cdot e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}} \color{red}{\neq} A_2 $$

So, that quoted statement is not correct.

\$A_2\$ is the factor to solve the boundary condition of the ODE (at \$t=0\$).

Comment: yes i forgot the - in the exponent, thanks for your answer!